# How to write test case for the PreparedStatement in java using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, prepared-statement

I am trying to write JUnit test class for PreparedStatement function, but not able to get how to do this. I tried with the mock data class, but still there was the problem in Connection object as its null. Below is the sample class :

```
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator;
import com.example.beans.SaveLegacy;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class InsertAgent implements PreparedStatementCreator {

    /** The query param. */
    private String queryParam;

    /** Input values */
    private SaveLegacy legacy;
    String systemCode;
    Integer documentId;

    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
      
            Base64 base64Decoder = new Base64();
            Clob clob = connection.createClob();    // Here the object connection is null.
            String decodedFileContent = new String(base64Decoder.decode(legacy.getAssociatedData()));
            clob.setString(1, decodedFileContent);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryParam);
        
        preparedStatement.setString(1, legacy.getACode());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, legacy.getGuid());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, systemCode);
                preparedStatement.setClob(4, clob);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, legacy.getAssociatedData());
                preparedStatement.setString(6, legacy.getModifiedByUserId());
                
        return preparedStatement;
    }
}
```

I am new to this, don't have much idea how to write Junit class for the above class.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
class InsertAgentTest {

 @Test
 public void testCreatePreparedStatement() {
   SaveLegacy saveLegacy = mock(SaveLegacy.class);
   when(saveLegacy.getGuid()).thenReturn("some guid");
   when(saveLegacy.getACode()).thenReturn("code");
   ...
   Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
   PreparedStatement ps = mock(PreparedStatement.class)
   when(connection.prepareStatement(...)).thenReturn(ps);
   InsertAgent agent = new Insertagent(saveLegacy, ...);
   agent.createPreparedStatement(connection);
   verify(ps).setString(1, "acode");
   ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! What will be the  import for mock in "mock(SaveLegacy.class);" ?

Comment: `org.mockito.Mockito.mock`